# smarty tpl foreach

Tags: php, foreach, smarty

I use the smarty tpl.

Now i have a php code and i want to use it in tpl:

Tis is the output from the array.

```
 stdClass Object
(
[Status] => success
[Time] => 2011-01-01 12:00:00
[IP] => 12.34.56.789
[Count] => 1
[Filter] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Sort] => ProductCode
        [Order] => DESC
        [Search] => 
        [ProductCode] => P001
        [ProductType] => 
    )

[Result] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Products] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Identifier] => 1
                        [ProductCode] => test
                        [ProductName] => test
                    )

            )

    )
```

Tis is the php code that works:

```
   foreach ($product_list->Result->Products as $product) {
        echo $product->ProductName;
}
```

I use the follow tpl code but this doesn't work

```
           //in php
    $smarty->assign("data", $product_list); 

     //in tpl file
    {foreach item=item from=$data}

<tr>
    <td align="center">{$item.Result->Products->ProductName}</td>
    <td align="center"></td>
    <td align="center"></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="" class="usuallink">{$header.order}</a></td>
</tr>
{/foreach}
```

Does anyone now how i can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code from php will look like this:

```
{foreach from=$data->Result->Products item=item}
    {$item->ProductName}
{/foreach}
```

in smarty3 it can look even more like pure php:

```
{foreach $data->Result->Products as $item}
    {$item->ProductName}
{/foreach}
```